# what is the best way to read a python function? down-up, right-left? or vice versa

Tags: python

edit: bad wording on original title "are most programing langs like python from bottom up and right to left"

question - are a lot of programming languages like python that you want to look at your statement from bottom up and right to left?

simple question i quess, yet i'm learning how to program in python and know (intermediate) how to make shell scripts in bash.

when i make bash scripts i start from the top and work my way down, yet with python it seems like i have to think about what i want and then backward engineer how to make the program run.

so does anyone have any ideas on to how to make this simpler for me to understand?
(when i do find something that works for the answer that i'm looking for in python that works, i always put a '''comment''' at the end to try to remember to look from bottom up and right to left, in that statement anyway).

this it seems (comments) are very helpful for me to understand more about what i'm trying to accomplish (especially when it comes to recursion), yet does anyone know of examples, discussions, (short cuts to understand), the backwardness of how to program a program?

one more question,

are programs just a lot of scripts put together in the proper sequences?

edit: thank you for your responses they are helpful.
moderators, please let others reply for a little bit longer, and then you can close it.

to those that have replied, i'm taking the MIT Introduction to Computer Science and Programming using Python to try to actually learn how to program with python and get a better understanding of programming in general.

to somewhat understand what i mean by what i stated above see a bash script that i wrote quite a while back ->
https://drive.google.com/open?id=13WtPvaabM9__hUWNOWzPOai9n34LeiWa
and me trying to turn it into a python program.  everything that is in it i just looked up on the web, read the docs, and asked some questions here, before taking the MIT class. python attempt ->
https://drive.google.com/open?id=10NesR4FONR8k1vegJjwKdHloC5r0JrWm

Comment: Um, what do you mean "you want to look at your statement from bottom up, and right to left" that is *the opposite* of how you read Python...

Comment: Python requires you to define functions before you call them, so in that sense you have to go to the bottom to find the main code, then look up to read the definitions of the functions it calls. But `bash` is also like that, too, so I don't understand your distinction. But maybe you don't use lots of functions in your bash scripts.

Comment: Some languages don't require this, e.g. PHP and Javascript. And some languages have all their code in functions, e.g. Lisp and C.

Answer (score 2):

You can write your program in python without using functions.

On the other hand, you can write shell scripts using functions.

So if you 'find something that works' and that code is organized in functions, then it was the choice of the developer to organize that code in functions.

Shell scripts tend to be short and are often used for one specific purpose.
In that case many people just write the code that is necessary without thinking to much about readability or code structure.

For longer scripts or programs people tend to switch to languages like python. At that point code layout and readability get more important and now many people structure the code into functions, because they made the experience that their code is easier to maintain and understand that way.

This is maybe the reason, the shell script examples you find most are 'top down left right', and the python examples are structured in functions and classes

Comment: thank you murphy.  look at what i said to andrea, i mean the same for you. take care.

Answer (score 1):

> are a lot of programming languages like python that you want to look at your statement from bottom up and right to left?

In many languages and frameworks understanding the execution flow can be pretty complicated! Your code may be grouped and called in many unexpected ways.

Programming languages also allow you to run code in parallel, so that you can have two pieces of code running at the same time. This is done using *threads* or *processes* or *asynchronous* programming.

As you have probably already seen, in Python there are functions, classes and modules. Those are used to "group" code so that it is easy to re-use, and also to define abstract concepts that make programming easy. Those structures make code flow more complicated (because you "jump" from a place to another), yet they are very powerful tools.

> when i make bash scripts i start from the top and work my way down, yet with python it seems like i have to think about what i want and then backward engineer how to make the program run.

Bash can get complicated too, in a way similar to Python. Look at [the script to install Docker](https://github.com/docker/docker-install/blob/master/install.sh): this is an example of a shell script that is not "top to bottom".

And, similarly, you can write simple Python scripts that are executed from top to bottom too. This is not true for all languages however (e.g. C or Java, where you *must* use functions).

> so does anyone have any ideas on to how to make this simpler for me to understand?

Experience is the key. Even old programmers have to spend quite some time to learn and understand new languages and frameworks they're not familiar with.

Writing comments and documentation (like you already do) can be helpful too: you can document how and when your functions should be called, you can document what functions are going to be called. Example:

```
def frobnicate():
    """This function transforms foo into baz"""
    # insert magic here

def main():
    """This is the program ingress point. It calls frobnicate() three times."""
    for i in range(3):
        frobnicate()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Call the ingress point, defined above
    main()
```

With free/open source software, you also have the advantage that you can look at the source. So, for example, if you want to know how a function `frobnicate()` gets called, you can look at the source for the keyword "frobnicate" and find your answer. It's not always straightforward, but it's a useful approach.

Comment: thank you, that actually makes sense to me.  i would like to give you a check mark, yet murphy helped out just as much.  i would welcome your advice into my nonunderstandings/misunderstanings/ununderstandings if/when i do post more (basically when i do post more).  thank you, take care.